# Fill a multidimensional array with characters from a file C#

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

So,I have written the code below to fill my multidimensional board with the characters I have read from a file called String.
Example if my file is:
abc
(new line)
def
the board array has t be filled with: { {'a','b','c'},{'d','e','f'}}
(the size of board is [counter,length])

Code:

```
char[,] board = new char[counter, length];

int k = 0;

while (((line = file.ReadLine()) != null) && (k < counter))
{
    char[] characters = line.ToCharArray();
    int l = 0;
    while (l < length)
    {
        foreach (char ch in characters)
        {
            board[k, l] = ch;
        }

        l++;
    }
    k++;
}
```

Comment: So what is the problem here you haven't mentioned at all? Should we just read and understand what is going on?

Comment: @ArdahanKisbet the problem is that the array is not filled ,it stays empty. Cause I've tried printing it out. If you have another way of making what I have made.

Comment: { {'a','b','c'}, {'d','e','f'} } is a jagged array. Do you need to fill a 2 dimensional array (which you've already done), or a jagged array?

Comment: @OguzOzgul 2 dimensional array. That was just an example I took. The problem is in the code why my array can't be filled.

Comment: where are `counter` and `length` set?

Comment: I run your code with a simple string "abc\r\bdef" and with StringReader and it works. You probably have an issue with how you are accessing the file, or while printing the array, which you did not provided the source code.

Comment: @DStanley i just posted a piece of my code , the counter and length are some  values i have found before doing this (that piece of code works fine).

Comment: @OguzOzgul //this is the code i print out my array:

Comment: @OguzOzgul  : for (int index = 0; index < counter; index++)
            {
                for(int jdex = 0; jdex < length; jdex++)
                {
                    Console.Write(board[index, jdex]);
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }

Comment: Ok I saw the problem now. Posting the answer

Comment: @OguzOzgul Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did not see it right away, but the problem is the for loop inside the while (l < length) loop.

The for loop iterates over the characters in the string, but `l` does not change during this iteration.

The fixed version of your code is as follows.

Note: string is already a sequence of `char`s so you don't have to convert it ToCharArray().

```
char[,] board = new char[counter, length];

int k = 0;

while (((line = file.ReadLine()) != null) && (k < counter))
{
    int l = 0;
    while (l < length)
    {
        // line is a string and we can access its characters with indexing
        board[k, l] = line[l];
        l++;
    }
    k++;
}
```